# How do I motivate myself to study a subject when the teacher couldn't care less about teaching it

Tags: teaching

So I am a Computer Science major final year under-graduate student.

I am studying 4 classes at the moment, and sadly, don't feel really good about any of them. The subjects are good, I love Computer Science, in general, but the teaching has been below average. The classes only consist of teachers coming to the class, reciting bullet points written on the PowerPoint, and leaving.

To make things worse, almost all of them expect us to write **exactly** as the prescribed text-book, even a different notation is frowned upon.

This is really getting on my head, because:

1. I am trying to learn (cram?) what is required for the exam, and I kind of suck at it.
2. I feel like I am ditching myself - because I learn nothing out of it.

I am starting to develop medical problems, like headaches, high blood pressure because of all the stress - the stress of doing things **exactly** as in the text book.

So I want to ask what is the most appropriate step to take in such a case? Have you experienced anything like this before? How did you cope with it?

Comment: This question will probably be closed as off-topic, but you should consider seeking help through your university's student health center. They should have resources to help you with your medical problems and stress management.

Comment: Depending on the number of units associated with each, four CS classes sounds like a pretty heavy load for anyone.  Could some of your problem be fixed if you cut back on your course load to something you could be successful at, even if the instructors aren't as helpful as you'd hoped?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton Cutting back doesn't seem like an option right now. I have been a decent student till now btw, GPA 3.6/4.

Comment: Because you'd rather fail by a certain deadline than succeed at a slower pace?

Comment: Learn in your spare time what you like most(and beyond the courses), and at a constant rate what you should learn In this way, you combine what you need to learn with what you want to learn.

Comment: @Ric Notice that in some countries universities might not have any student health center.

Comment: Question for those voting to close: What about this question could not happen to a graduate student?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I've never heard of a graduate program that was devoted to the kind of rote learning that the question describes as the main problem.  If it's about how to deal with stress and discouragement, on the other hand, we've got a bunch of good Q&A about this already.

Comment: @jakebeal I'd argue that a university like the OP's, which has such a bad undergraduate program, probably has a similar graduate program as well.

Comment: "almost all of them expect us to write exactly as the prescribed textbook, even a different notation is frowned upon." Conventions in Computer Science are important. They make it easier for your instructors, your classmates, your future coworkers, and yourself to read code (or even scan that code and those notations visually because the human mind has a very powerful visual pattern recognition capability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today is September 16.  If you move fast you may be able to switch to some better-taught classes.

My guess is you are past the drop-add deadline.  You may need to get approval from someone quite high up.  You may need to assert yourself.

Step one is to look at what other courses are being offered this semester that would fit into your program of studies and your interests.  Step two is to visit those classes.  You should arrive five minutes early, introduce yourself to the instructor before class, and give some simple white lie such as "I'm thinking of signing up for this class next year; do you mind if I sit in today?"

If you fall in love with the class and the instructor, then at the end, when you thank him or her for letting you sit in, you should come clean and say that you would like to add the course to your schedule.  Don't say anything about the other course you would be dropping.  Say, "If I can get administrative approval to add this class after the deadline, would that be all right with you?  I would work very hard to catch up on all the material that's been covered so far.  I have a such-and-so GPA."

If the instructor seems pressed for time, just say thank you and ask if you might contact him or her later with a follow-up question.

It's your education.  It's fine for you to be pro-active and advocate for yourself, with polite persistence.

Edit: I just re-read your question and saw that you are an undergrad.  I will now have to vote to close.  Sorry.